# Loop through an Object to check the functions that return true

Tags: javascript, function

I have an object like this one:

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    uniqueProps: [],
    browserUID: '',
    browserFonts: '',
    isIPhonePad: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i);
    },
    isDesktop: function() {
        return !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|android/i);
    },
    isAndroid: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i);
    },
    isFirefox: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i);
    },
    isIOS7: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i);
    },
    isChromeCrios: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/chrome|crios/i);
    },
    isIPad: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
    }
}
```

(FYI: There are more functions inside the object)

So I want to go through "BrowserDetect" and check which of those functions inside it return "true" and get the function's name too.

What's the easy way to achieve that? I tried to use the jquery $.each, but without success.

Comment: You don't have "a method". You have an object that contains several properties, some of which are storing functions that can be called as methods of instances of that object.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.keys()` with `Array#filter` to iterate the object and return all truthy function names:

```
Object.keys(BrowserDetect).filter(function(key) {
  var f = BrowserDetect[key];

  return typeof f === 'function' && f();
});
```

```js
var BrowserDetect = {
    uniqueProps: [],
    browserUID: '',
    browserFonts: '',
    isIPhonePad: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i);
    },
    isDesktop: function() {
        return !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|android/i);
    },
    isAndroid: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i);
    },
    isFirefox: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i);
    },
    isIOS7: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i);
    },
    isChromeCrios: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/chrome|crios/i);
    },
    isIPad: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
    }
};

var result = Object.keys(BrowserDetect).filter(function(key) {
  var f = BrowserDetect[key];
  
  return typeof f === 'function' && f();
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why not `.filter()`? It's a reduce designed for this case.

Comment: @squint - can't argue with that. Filter is better then reduce here. Refactored.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a non-functional solution in pure js. It's fairly straightforward once you consider that a property can be a function as well. Once you use `call()` method on the property it will run the underlying function.

```js
var BrowserDetect = {
    uniqueProps: [],
    browserUID: '',
    browserFonts: '',
    isIPhonePad: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i);
    },
    isDesktop: function() {
        return !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|android/i);
    },
    isAndroid: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i);
    },
    isFirefox: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i);
    },
    isIOS7: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i);
    },
    isChromeCrios: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/chrome|crios/i);
    },
    isIPad: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
    }
}

var functions = [];
for(var prop in BrowserDetect){
    if(typeof(BrowserDetect[prop])=="function" && BrowserDetect[prop].call()){
        functions.push(prop);
       }
  }
console.log(functions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use common for ... in loop

```
for (var functionName in BrowserDetect) {
  if (!BrowserDetect.hasOwnProperty(functionName)
    || typeof BrowserDetect[functionName] !== "function") continue
  if (BrowserDetect[functionName]())
    return functionName
}
```

or Object.keys

```
Object.keys(BrowserDetect).reduce(
  (current, fnName) => typeof BrowserDetect[fnName] === "function" && BrowserDetect[fnName]() ? fnName : current )
```